# parse nested function to extract each inner function in python

Tags: python

I have a nested expression as below

```
 expression = 'position(\'a\' IN Concat("function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" ,  "function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" ))'
```

I want the output as by retreiving nested function first and then outer functions

```
['Concat("function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" ,  "function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" )','position(\'a\' IN Concat("function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" ,  "function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" ))']
```

Below is the code I have tried

```
 result = []
 for i in range(len(expression)):
     if expression[i]=="(":
        a.append(i)
     elif expression[i]==")":
          fromIdx=a.pop()
          fromIdx2=max(a[-1],expression.rfind(",", 0, fromIdx))
          flag=False
          for (fromIndex, toIndex) in first_Index:
             if fromIdx2 + 1 >= fromIndex and i <= toIndex:
                 flag=True
                 break
          if flag==False:
             result.append(expression[fromIdx2+1:i+1])
```

But this works only if expression is separated by **','**
for ex:

```
expression = 'position(\'a\' , Concat("function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" ,  "function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" ))'
```

and result for this expression from my code will be correct as exprected.
In first expression ,I mentioned ,there is **IN** operator instead of **','** hence my code doesnt work.

Please help

Comment: pls format this.

Comment: @leoOrion have formatted properly now.Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be reliable, you need a full-fledged SQL parser. Fortunately, there is an out-of-box solution for that: https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/. As soon as you have a parsed token tree, you can walk through it and do what you need:

```
import sqlparse

def extract_functions(tree):
    res = []
    def visit(token):
        if token.is_group:
            for child in token.tokens:
                visit(child)
        if isinstance(token, sqlparse.sql.Function):
            res.append(token.value)
    visit(tree)
    return res

extract_functions(sqlparse.parse(expression)[0])
```

Explanation.
`sqlparse.parse(expression)` parses the string and returns a tuple of statements. As there is only one statement in the example, we can just take the first element. If there are many statements, you should rather iterate over all tuple elements.

`extract_functions` recursively walks over a parsed token tree depth first (since you want inner calls appear before outer ones) using `token.is_group` to determine if the current token is a leaf, tests if the current token is a function, and if it is, appends its string representation (`token.value`) to the result list.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer.will it work for any kind of complex expressions and return the nested functions starting from innermost. And is it feasible to use the package sqlparse?Any disadvantage of using sqlparse?

Comment: It should work unless there are bugs in the parser. I don't know what may be disadvantages. May be if you have some very special restrictions on using third-party packages, this may cause troubles. But in general case it should be perfectly OK. It is one of the coolest things in Python, that you can find an out-of-box package virtually for everything.

Comment: okay thankyou.Can you please explain me this code.

Comment: Added an explanation.

Comment: Have found one issue in this code recently saying it will not support spaces after function name example ```upper (name)``` will not work.Can you please help me with this

Comment: Looks like a bug in `sqlparse`. You can report it here https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/issues